# consulta con solo los usuarios que se coinicidan con el dia de hoy

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

en mi BD en mongo en donde el formato se expresa de la siguiente manera: 2019-07-21T14:36:12.076Z quiero hacer un "find" en donde me traiga solo los usuarios con la fecha de hoy, utilizo moment pero no se como expresar la condicion dentro del query, aca el codigo a ver si alguien puede darme una mano:

```
const today     = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

let ListarUsuariosPagosHoy =
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    let list = Pago.find(
        { 
            
    "fecha_fin" : today
    
        }
    , (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
            if (!err) {

                return registrosEncontrados

            }
        }
    )
    resolve(list);

})
```

aca solo me trae unica y exclusivamente los del el momento en donde momentjs otorga la fecha y hora pero quiero que sea los de todo el dia, alguien con una idea? de antemano gracias

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEMA**

Se necesita realizar una consulta a una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/) de tal forma que los registros devueltos se correspondan con un día específico. El campo que almacena el dato requerido es de tipo [`Date`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/bson-types/index.html#date).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para realizar la consulta debemos entender 2 cosas:

1. El tipo `Date` almacena un valor que se corresponde con la zona horaria `UTC`.
2. La evaluación de fechas las podemos hacer mediante operadores de comparación, ya que el tipo `Date` almacena un valor tipo entero de 64 bits, que representa la cantidad de milisegundos transcurridos desde el 01/01/1970 ([*Unix Epoch*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix)).

**La fecha**

No necesitas ninguna librería para convertir, manipular o transformar las fechas en este caso. Puedes usar los métodos [`getUTC*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date) del objeto `Date` de Javascript para escribir el rango de fechas que necesitas.

Por ejemplo, si deseo todos los documentos almacenados en la Base de Datos para el día de hoy (04/Ago/2020), necesito asegurarme que los documentos devueltos se encuentren en el intervalo: `04-08-2020 00:00:00.000z` y `04-08-2020 23:59:59.999z` (ambos inclusive).

¿Cómo obtengo estos valores? Pues allí intervienen los métodos `getUTC*` para poder identificar el valor adecuado del día, mes y año correspondientes a la zona horaria UTC de tal forma que no dependa de la zona horaria del cliente que ejecuta la consulta.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
let today = new Date('2020-08-04'); // formato YYYY-MM-DD

console.log(today); // Muestra "2020-08-04T00:00:00.000Z"

console.log(`Día del mes en horario local: ${today.getDate()}`); // en zonas horarias negativas se muestra 3
console.log(`Día del mes en horario UTC: ${today.getUTCDate()}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Bien, visto esto, podemos entonces construir un tipo `Date` usando la fecha UTC a partir de la fecha del sistema. La idea es crear el limite inferior y el límite superior (las bandas de fecha) para la búsqueda, de tal forma que podamos hacer la comparación usando los operadores `$gte` (mayor o igual que) y `$lte` (menor o igual que).

Por ejemplo:

```js
let today = new Date(); // fecha del sistema local


let desde = new Date(
  today.getUTCFullYear(),
  today.getUTCMonth(),
  today.getUTCDate()
);
let hasta = new Date(
  today.getUTCFullYear(),
  today.getUTCMonth(),
  today.getUTCDate(),
  23, 59, 59, 999
);

console.log(desde);
console.log(hasta);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se observa, los valores devueltos tendrán en cuenta la diferencia horaria, es decir, la hora mostrada dependerá de la zona horaria del cliente.

Esto parece confuso, pero es muy sencillo si hacemos las matemáticas adecuadas:

Si un cliente se encuentra en una zona horaria negativa, por ejemplo GMT-0400 (Caracas - La Paz) el valor devuelto por `desde` se ve así para el día 04 de agosto:

```
"2020-08-04T04:00:00.000Z"
```

Y el valor devuelto por `hasta` se vería así:

```
"2020-08-05T03:59:59.999Z"
```

Esto significa que cuando en la ubicación local GMT-0400 son las 00 horas, en la zona UTC son las 04 horas del mismo día. Es decir, para obtener la hora de Caracas debo restar 04 unidades de hora a la Hora UTC. Fácil ¿cierto?

Para zonas horarias positivas la cosa es aún más desconcertante. Mi zona horaria actual es GMT+0200 Hora de Verano de Europa Central. En mi ordenador el código anterior muestra lo siguiente para `desde`:

```
"2020-08-03T22:00:00.000Z"
```

y esto es para `hasta`:

```
"2020-08-04T23:59:59.999Z"
```

Significa que cuando son las 00 horas en mi zona local del día 4, son exactamente las 22 horas del día 3 (¡el día anterior!) en la zona UTC.

Aclarado este punto, podemos estar seguros que la información consultada a nuestra BD usando estos valores para las fechas (y horas) será siempre coherente con la fecha y hora del sistema local, sin importar la zona horaria en la que se encuentre el cliente.

**La consulta**

La consulta la vamos a construir usando el operador [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/and/index.html) y los operadores de comparación [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html) y [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/query/lte/index.html).

Queremos que nuestra consulta devuelva los documentos cuyo valor en el campo `fecha_fin` esté comprendido entre 2 fechas. Para ello usamos el operador `$and` para indicar que queremos que se cumplan las dos condiciones: `fecha_fin` es mayor o igual a la fecha calculada en `desde` y es menor o igual que la fecha calculada en `hasta`.

Si la fecha la vamos a calcular en base a la fecha del sistema que ejecuta nuestro servidor Node, la consulta podría quedar así:

```js
let today = new Date();

let desde = new Date(
  today.getUTCFullYear(),
  today.getUTCMonth(),
  today.getUTCDate()
);
let hasta = new Date(
  today.getUTCFullYear(),
  today.getUTCMonth(),
  today.getUTCDate(),
  23, 59, 59, 999
);

const query = {
  $and: [
    {fecha_fin: {$gte: desde}},
    {fecha_fin: {$lte: hasta}}
  ]
}

Pago.find(query)
  .then(results => {
    results.forEach(item => {
      console.log(item);
    });
    //...
  })
  .catch(errorHandler);
```

En caso de que la fecha sea recibida mediante un tipo `String`, debemos asegurarnos que la misma cumpla el formato admitido por el constructor `Date()`. Por ejemplo:

```
let today = new Date('2020-08-04'); // Formato: YYYY-MM-DD
```

Esta sería forma de realizar la consulta para que devuelva los documentos en un rango de fechas específico.